# API for connecting to Quickboooks Desktop in v3

Tags: java, desktop, quickbooks, ipp-qbd-sync

I want to know how can i connect to Quickbooks desktop using the v3 api. I have successfully connected to Quickbooks online. Now i need to connect to Desktop. I have already done it using the V2 API but since its deprecated i need to upgrade to V3 API.

For QBD(Quickbooks Desktop) i have found the following references

[Reference](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0050_documentation/manuals)

The link has documentation for Quickbooks SDK and Quickbooks WebConnector. Which one should be used for communicating with Quickbooks Desktop?

Also i found the following documentation

[Reference](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_deprecated/qbd_v3/qbd_v3_reference/010_calling_data_services/00100_requests_and_responses/0010_requests)

Is it possible to send XML/JSON request to a service URL in quickbooks for QBD as shown in the above URL reference??

Any help on how to proceed with quickbooks desktop integration would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you have an existing QuickBooks desktop v2 app that has been published already, AND have talked to Intuit about the pricing changes for QuickBooks desktop apps:**

Then you'll be grandfathered in, and can use the v3 QuickBooks desktop APIs that are documented [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_deprecated/qbd_v3).

Set up Sync Manager on your QuickBooks desktop computer (there's an option in the menu) and you'll be able to choose that company when you go through the OAuth process.

**Otherwise:**

You need to use the QuickBooks SDK instead of the v3 APIs. These are instead documented [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb).

Comment: For using quickbooks SDK do i need to generate qbxml and post it to a URL? Is there any sample code for quickbooks desktop connection with java? I have ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar, ipp-java-qbapihelper-1.2.0.jar, ipp-v3-java-data-2.0.1.jar jars from v3 SDK and they work for QB online but not sure if they would be used for desktop as well

Comment: You DO need to generate qbXML. Instead of posting it to a URL, you'll use the Web Connector (which wraps stuff in SOAP) or the COM interface. If you download the SDK there are 600 pages of documentation on this, along with some Java samples. The IPP DevKits you have *will not work* with QuickBooks desktop unless you've been grandfathered in as an existing v2 app.

Comment: Thanks for the info on this. I have started working on the webservice to be used by the web connector. Just one question that i had is that in sendRequestXML() method, where qbXML is generated and sent in response can we add multiple requests in one xml like gettings items list as well as Orders list from Quickbooks?

Comment: Yes. http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_FAQ#How_can_I_send_more_than_one_request_at_once.3F